# Illustrator Template Won't Toggle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working in a file that has a template/guide thing that I can't figure out how to toggle. Does anybody have experience with these?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Video Guides for the artboard.

Select the Artboard Tool and you will have 3 toggle options in the Control Bar across the top of the screen. You can also bring up the **Artboard Options** dialog by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and toggling the video guides in that dialog.

[image: video guides]

Comment: You are my hero. <3 (no romo (not romantic (I'm trying to get that started))).